# question about RSA sign/verify scheme

Tags: rsa, signature

could you please explain what is the problem here?:

I'm trying to simulate sign/verify scenario with RSA keys. For simplicity I use 64bits keys:

```
PK = {BE1EE24B5ACD9DE5, 10001}
SK = {BE1EE24B5ACD9DE5, 15D231A2C5B605C1}
```

and do the calculations using http://extranet.cryptomathic.com/rsacalc/index

scenario 1 - Ok:

```
m = 0123456789ABCDEF
```

using Decrypt method (SIGN) I'm getting signature: 43437cd86b6a2cce

then using Encrypt method (VERIFY) on signature I'm getting back original message (m): 0123456789abcdef

scenario 2 - something goes wrong:

```
m = FEDCBA9876543210
```

SIGN = b3baca40fe26f5a1

VERIFY = 40bdd84d1b86942b

why VERIFY method doesn't produce original message here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RSA operation always produces an answer modulo the modulus.

Normally, we are careful to have a 'plaintext' which is smaller than the modulus, and hence the end result is the same.  After all, the fundamental identity for RSA is:

$$(M^d \bmod N)^ e \bmod N = M \bmod N$$

If $M < N$, then the right hand side simplifies to $M$

However, in this case, you have an initial input `FEDCBA9876543210` which is actually larger than the modulus `BE1EE24B5ACD9DE5`.  When you do this, you end up with an end result which is `FEDCBA9876543210 mod BE1EE24B5ACD9DE5 = 40BDD84D1B86942B`

That answers the immediate question you asked; however as you dig further into RSA, you should be aware of the following:

- When we use RSA, we (almost) never apply the RSA operation directly to the value given by the application (hash result, plaintext); instead, we apply a 'padding' operation first, to avoid potential attacks that exploit the homomorphic properties (and determinism in the case of encryption) that the raw RSA operation has
- During the signature operation, we really can't call the RSA operation 'decryption' (as we're not actually decrypting something that has been previously encrypted).  Normally, it is called a 'signing' or 'signature generation'.

Comment: ... and the mathematical operation just *modular exponentiation with the public or private exponent*.